Container `cmd.cat/lspci` timeout
I was using cmd.cat/lspci container in some of my tests.
Suddenly today start failing.
docker run cmd.cat/lspci
Unable to find image 'cmd.cat/lspci:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://cmd.cat/v2/": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
See 'docker run --help'.

The connection seems to respond ~20 seconds.
(base) time curl -vvv https://cmd.cat/v2/
* Host cmd.cat:443 was resolved.
* IPv6: 2606:4700:3035::ac43:a3ae, 2606:4700:3031::6815:2aa5
* IPv4: 172.67.163.174, 104.21.42.165
*   Trying 172.67.163.174:443...
* Connected to cmd.cat (172.67.163.174) port 443
* ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 / X25519 / id-ecPublicKey
* ALPN: server accepted h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=cmd.cat
*  start date: Mar 30 17:02:26 2024 GMT
*  expire date: Jun 28 17:02:25 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "cmd.cat" matched cert's "cmd.cat"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=E1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
*   Certificate level 0: Public key type EC/prime256v1 (256/128 Bits/secBits), signed using ecdsa-with-SHA384
*   Certificate level 1: Public key type EC/secp384r1 (384/192 Bits/secBits), signed using ecdsa-with-SHA384
*   Certificate level 2: Public key type EC/secp384r1 (384/192 Bits/secBits), signed using ecdsa-with-SHA384
* using HTTP/2
* [HTTP/2] [1] OPENED stream for https://cmd.cat/v2/
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:method: GET]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:scheme: https]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:authority: cmd.cat]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:path: /v2/]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [user-agent: curl/8.5.0]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [accept: */*]
> GET /v2/ HTTP/2
> Host: cmd.cat
> User-Agent: curl/8.5.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing


... 
Delay here...
...


< HTTP/2 200 
< date: Thu, 02 May 2024 22:17:59 GMT
< content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< content-length: 2
< docker-distribution-api-version: registry/2.0
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< age: 125665
< via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.0)
< cache-control: max-age=14400
< cf-cache-status: STALE
< last-modified: Wed, 01 May 2024 11:23:34 GMT
< accept-ranges: bytes
< report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v4?s=IpLVNEn4p5iW9zVaiyAwXcgB6sc%2BZbBHrJQ2Ms7Dq4L7DgtRR2Vg0SrURC0aSH%2FlfWheqByQf7G0MmQRHYn2yXTfrAMnCmcBZtyghjuje5hy8MDStBMIb5Fp"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
< nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
< server: cloudflare
< cf-ray: 87db61f93c3030bd-SEA
< alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400
< 
* Connection #0 to host cmd.cat left intact

{}
real    0m19.557s
user    0m0.046s
sys 0m0.015s
(base) 

I tried both local and multiple servers and same issue. Is there a way to increase timeout at docker run or docker pull or another public docker images with lspci.


Dockerfile
# Use an official Ubuntu base image
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Update packages and install pciutils
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y pciutils

# Set the default command to run when starting the container
CMD ["bash"]

End up building my own container.
